# IE 8 (and likely earlier) CSS Disaster

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, cross-browser

I made the mistake of designing a site using the latest versions of safari/firefox and chrome.  I briefly checked it was looking ok on IE 10 but didn't put too much into fallbacks.  I then started using 'sexier' css techniques and forgot about IE.

I have no defence, it was a foolish mistake to make.

The site looks dreadful in Earlier versions of I.E. It was briefly tested on I.E8.  A nav bar spans the page, entypo font doesn't display and a spinner is all messed up.  Thats on the first page, I haven't been able to view the others yet.

To make matters worse I use a mac, the VM for windows I have on it is running windows 8 and I can't install the older versions of IE without first installing an older version of Windows.

It's close to being a disaster.  The site is located at kingpetroleum.co.uk and any help is hugely appreciated.

EDIT:
Fontface details as not working

```
@font-face{font-family:'EntypoRegular';
src:url(data:font/woff;charset=utf-8;base64,d09GRg ...... ...... ..... etc);
src:url(data:fnt/truetype)format(''truetype); //deliberately mispelt there to avoid pasting a ton of code
url('entypo-webfont-webfont.svg#EntypoRegular') format('svg');
    font-weight:normal;
    font-style:normal
```

Comment: Some screenshots or link to the site would be helpful to see the extent of the problem

Comment: you need to give us more information so we can help you

Comment: This might help view non-interactive features of the site in various IEs: http://netrenderer.com/

Comment: There is a nice service for converting font-faces at http://www.fontsquirrel.com/ - it even spits out the CSS you need, ready for use on web.

Answer (score 6):

If you have designed an entire website without taking IE into consideration there is no easy fix for it. I would recommend using an IE only stylesheet.

Something like this:

```
<!--[if IE]>
<link href='ie-style.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<![endif]-->
```

Then restyle your element's so they are IE friendly. This is for all IE browsers (excluding ie10) but there are tags which will only use this stylesheet in specific versions.

Comment: Cheers Simon, I think this might be the only way.  There are a lot of pages but I my mistake.

Comment: "*This is for all IE browsers*" -- IE10 discontinued the use of of conditional comments, FYI. In this case that works out nicely because IE10 renders the site fine as is :)

Comment: @xec - cheers for that update.  I've just tried using the development mode of IE10 to view the site in IE8 to test the css3Pie mentioned below but it doens't seem to be getting called.  Could this be because of that?  Not sure if using dev mode changes how the browser reacts to IF IE if IE10 ignores them

Comment: @SteveGreen IE10 in "Internet Explorer 8" browser mode will apply conditional comments, you can verify with http://jsfiddle.net/tsPVD/show/ - the text "I AM IE!" should appear in IE8 mode but not IE10 mode

Comment: @xec, thanks, I think I was using the wrong path, it detects the IE fine now but the CSSPIE can't be used.  Too much time to target the individual css3 elements.

Would you mind taking a moment and having a look at the index page?  I can't see why the nav is across the whole site

Comment: It's ok, seems it doesn't like aside ?

Comment: @SteveGreen Ah, yes - html5 semantic elements are not supported in IE8 without a shim http://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/

Comment: Thank you so much! That's that solved :)  I had changed it to a div and set css but nicer to leave as it was.

Don't suppose you know about font faces too?  Entypo?

Answer (score 4):

Have you considered using a JS script like PIE.js?

http://css3pie.com/documentation/pie-js/

Comment: This is also a very good options and could save a lot of time

Comment: I'm now trying to get it to work but having some difficulties.  I've added it to my head tags and using IE10 in dev mode for IE8 but it doesn't seem to be getting called

Answer (score 2):

It shouldn't be so hard to fix the problems in your page.
First of all, use modernizr (http://modernizr.com/), it has the HTML5 shiver that will help with the new semantic tags, also it's a must in any webpage these days. Also, use normalize (http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/), it'll help a lot in cross-browser compatibility.

If you're using media queries for big screens (mobile first approach), you'll have to use Respond.js or just add a conditional style for IE (as cited in previous answers).

For the gradients, just provide a png as background, or live with solid backgrounds on unsupported browsers (graceful degradation).

The same applies to border-radius.

The 3d carrousel shouldn't rely in CSS3, unless it's thought to be an added thing to browsers that supports it (progressive enhancement). If it's important, use jQuery.

The font icons should work in IE8+, maybe there's a problem with your code, or a font format is lacking. You should use icomoon.io (you can import a svg font to it).

With good code and sticking to the good practices (using graceful degradation and/or progressive enhancement), you shouldn't have any big problem with IE8. Just keep in mind that your page won't (and shouldn't) render the same in all browsers but it mustn't lose it's essence.

Comment: thanks for taking the time to answer and for the advice.  I'm now looking at the modernizer and normalise you mentioned. 

Gradients / border radius and the carousel can stay as they are.  I'll include a message that suggests users update their browser for the best experience or something like that.

The font is trickier for me, I remember having problems with it a while ago.  I've pasted the code for it in the question, would you mind having a look?  Thanks again

Comment: You're not using eot format. IE8 uses only eot, so you should use it. The best way to make it work fine, if you're not confident in your code, is use icomoon. It'll give you a bit of work to redo everything, but it works really well in most browsers and is done the right way.

Comment: Forgot to mention, here's a good and short article about it:
http://tatiyants.com/how-to-get-ie8-to-support-html5-tags-and-web-fonts/ (ignore the tags thing, just stick to modernizr).